# Direct Dialing a phone number with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am doing the following.

1) adding the white-list to the config.xml

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

2)And then in my code:

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-555-1234">call this number</a>
```

It works and the number is dialed.

But the number appears "typed in" in the dial-pad the user still has to tap dial to make the call.

Is it the limitation of the "web-view" or am i missing a trick here?
How can i make it so when the user taps the number the call is made and not just typed in?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No i did not..it seem it is the limitation of the web view in which the phonegap apps run OR the plugin is made as such..as of now the use still has to tap one more time to make the call.